# How to combine two strings i Haskell and return a new string

Tags: haskell

How to concatinate two strings . For example I have two lists
`["me","you","he"]` and  `["she","they","it"]`. I want to form a new list in which every correspondging strings are combined togatheer, like
`["meshe","youthey","heit"]`. Now my question is: how can I combine two strings

Comment: Could also do `combine xs ys = [x ++ y | (x, y) <- zip xs ys]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
combine = zipWith (++)
```

[zipWith](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) takes two lists, and applies the function given to the first item of both lists, then the second, etc. If one list is longer than the other, its extra items will be skipped.

The `++` function takes two lists and joins them together. A string is just a list of characters.

`"hello " ++ "world" == "hello world"`

usage:

```
λ> combine ["me","you","he"] ["she","they","it"]
["meshe","youthey","heit"]
λ> combine [] []
[]
λ> combine ["me", "you"] ["she"]
["meshe"]
λ>
```

The `++` operator is very basic though, so you might be better continuing reading whatever learning material you're using before coming to stackoverflow, as you'll have a lot of questions which I expect will be answered in your book.

If you don't want to use zipWith, you can write it very simply with recursion like so:

```
combine [] _ = []
combine _ [] = []
combine (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x ++ y) : combine xs ys
```

Usage is the same as before.

Comment: what if don't want to use zipwith function

Comment: @UmairAziz see my edit. It's a pretty simple recursive function.

Comment: @UmairAziz Why wouldn't you? As a general rule, you should try to avoid explicit recursion; it's a sign you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @chepner I know it's bad style but a lot of the time I find an explicit recursion function a lot more readable than a foldl/foldr. In this case it's a no brainer though.

Comment: @chepner: because this is a homework question and some student that does not want to to find a job later.